# Is there a way to find out in which terminal a Node.js process is being run in?

Tags: javascript, command-line

I want to know in my code what kind of terminal the process is being run in (CMD, PowerShell, Bash, ...)
Is there some cross-platform way to display some info about the current terminal or an npm module I can use?
I've searched for a while now but can't seem to find anything on this.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with it?

Comment: [`process.ppid`](https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_process_ppid) probably helps

Comment: @DeepakDixit I'm working on some graphical stuff for CLIs and they tend to render differently on CMD, PowerShell, Git Bash and zsh. I want to figure out which ones work the best and tell the user they might experience bad rendering.

Answer (score 0):

`process.env.SHELL` is the closest I could find.

It's `'/usr/local/bin/zsh'` in my case (Homebrew `zsh` on macOS).

I have no Windows at hand to compare the results.

May be unreliable, if I start `bash` from my `zsh`, or when I start PowerShell.app, I still get `'/usr/local/bin/zsh'`...

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that and get back to you.